# Same parameters,different methods

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I'm making an API in asp mvc 4.

I have 2 methods, `GetAllBooks()` and `GetPopularBooks()`.

To get all books, I call localhost:xxxxx/api/books/, and I get the correct result.
How can I query the popular books? Both methods are parameterless and our info here is not really helpful.

All help is appreciated!

Comment: You are not newbie here, please pay more attention when choosing tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although this could be achieved using "Routing by Action Name" http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-in-aspnet-web-api. I strongly suggest that GetPopularBooks() be treated as GetAllBooks but with a filter of popularity.

e.g.

```
public IEnumerable<Books> GetAllBooks([FromUri]bool? IsPopular = null)
{
     if(IsPopular.HasValue)
     { //do something
       //return filtered
     }

     //return all
}
```

Urls:

```
http://localhost/api/books
http://localhost/api/books?isPopular=true
```